# Is there a 'neat' way of solving this equation (PDE)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have an equation $x(t,y(t,s)) = \ln(s) + \lambda(u - s\partial_{s}u)$ where $u = u(t,s)$ and $\lambda$ is just an arbitrary value. I would like to solve this equation for $u$, is there a neat way to solve this? I don't really work with PDE's (I'm more of a stats person) so this might be incredibly trivial, but I'm not really too sure what to do...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are $x,y$ unknown?

Comment: I think both $x$ and $y$ are known

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are unknown, will it change anything?

Comment: For me, the wording ambiguous. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \lambda\left(u - s\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial s}\right)=x(t,y(t,s)) - \ln(s)  \qquad (1)$$
Ultimately $x(t,y(t,s)) - \ln(s)$ is a function of $t$ and $s$. So, let : $\quad x(t,y(t,s)) - \ln(s)=f(t,s)$
$$ \lambda\left(u - s\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right)=f(t,s)$$
Let $u(t,s)=sv(t,s)\quad\to\quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial s}=v+s\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}$

$ \lambda\left(sv - s\left(v+s\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}\right)\right)=f(t,s)$

$$ \lambda\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}=-\frac{f(t,s)}{s^2}$$
$$v=-\frac{1}{\lambda}\int \frac{f(t,s)}{s^2}ds +g(t)$$

$$u(t,s)=-\frac{s}{\lambda}\int \frac{1}{s^2}f(t,s)ds +s\:g(t)$$
where $g(t)$ is an arbitrary function and $f(t,s)=x(t,y(t,s)) - \ln(s)$

This shows that the function $u(t,s)$ can be expressed in terms of the functions $x(t,y(t,s))$ and $y(t,s)$.

On the other hand, the equation (1) alone cannot determine the functions  $x(t,y(t,s))$ and $y(t,s)$.

If it was expected to derive $x(t,y(t,s))$ and $y(t,s)$ from equation (1), then there is something missing in the wording of the question (at least one more equation should be necessary).

If equation (1) comes from a preliminary calculus in order to solve another problem (for example another PDE with the method of characteristics), the initial problem must be posted, because the present wording forgets something from the preliminary calculus. Of course this is only a guess.

Comment: This is what I had in my mind. I think OP is missing some info about $x,y$. Otherwise, looking at the function $f$, it looks like we don't care $\ln(s)$ or $\lambda$. I had a similar way. I defined the function $f$ slightly different,  $f(t,s)=\displaystyle\frac{-\lambda(x(t,y(t,s))-\ln(s))}{s^2}$. Then LHS becomes derivative of $\displaystyle\frac{u}{s}$.